# AWS CDK cross-stack references and deployment order

Tags: aws-cdk

What's the way to overcome the circular dependency problem in AWS CDK:
Let's imagine I have a stack for ECS cluster and a stack for ECS Service (several of them):

```
export class EcsClusterStack extends cdk.Stack {
    public readonly cluster: ecs.Cluster
    ...
}
```

and

```
export class EcsServiceStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, cluster: ecs.ICluster) { }
}
```

Now, I can compose my app:

```
const app = new cdk.App();
const vpc = new VpcStack(app,  'vpc');
const cluster = new ClusterStack(app, 'ecs', vpc.vpc);

const service = new EcsServiceStack(app, 'ecs-service', cluster.cluster);
```

Let's assume, after that, I want to migrate my ECS service from one cluster to another. I would create another ECS Cluster stack and pass it to ECS Service, but here the thing:
AWS CDK automatically generates Outputs (in Cluster stack there are outputs like cluster name, etc), and then, when I want to migrate my ECS Service to another cluster and if I pass another ICluster object down to ECS Service stack constructor AWS CDK tries to remove Outputs/Exports from my previous cluster definition and that's obviously going to fail upon deploy since it cannot remove exports from Cluster stack until there is the service that relies on it. Finally, I see an error like:

```
0 | 7:15:19 PM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack            | ecs User Initiated
0 | 7:15:26 PM | UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_P | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack            | ecs Export ecs:ExportsOutputFnGetAttdefaultasgspotInstanceSecurityGroup2D2AFE98GroupId1084B7B2 cannot be deleted as it is in use by ecs-service
```

If there was a way to force ECS service stack to deploy first that would solve the problem, but it seems AWS CDK always deploys dependency first (ECS cluster in my case) and that fails deployment. So is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Have you been able to find a workaround for this? I am facing similar issues.

Comment: @kichik: I ended up using the same approach

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AWS added an official [workaround](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/@aws-cdk/core/README.md#removing-automatic-cross-stack-references). It allows you to manually create an export in the dependent stack. When you need to remove an export:

1. Create the export manually
2. Remove its usage
3. Deploy
4. Remove the manual export
5. Deploy again

```
this.exportAttribute(this.bucket.bucketName)
```

---

One workaround I found is forcing CDK to split the deployment to two steps. First I deploy the stack that uses the export so it doesn't use it anymore. Then I deploy the stack that creates the export to remove the export after it's no longer used. Even if you specify the stack name on the command, it still deploys all stacks it depends on. So I have to use the `--exclusively` flag.

```
cdk deploy --exclusively ecs-service
cdk deploy
```

In your case you would need a step before all that of creating the new cluster and deploying the stack so you have something new to import in `ecs-service`.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3414) for this on GitHub.

---

I created the following script to help automate the process. It phases out the exports in two deployments. On the first deployment it restores any removed exports but marks them to be removed. This allows the first deployment to safely remove its usage. On the second deployment the script actually removes the exports after no other stack is using them.

To use the script you have to separate the synth and deploy steps and run the script in between them.

```
cdk synth && python phase-out-ref-exports.py && cdk deploy --app cdk.out --all
```

It requires permissions to read the stack, so it will probably not work well with cross-account deployments.

```
# phase-out-ref-exports.py
import json
import os
import os.path
 
from aws_cdk import cx_api
import boto3
import botocore.exceptions
 
 
def handle_template(stack_name, account, region, template_path):
    # get outputs from existing stack (if it exists)
    try:
        # TODO handle different accounts
        print(f"Checking exports of {stack_name}...")
        stack = boto3.client("cloudformation", region_name=region).describe_stacks(StackName=stack_name)["Stacks"][0]
        old_outputs = {
            o["OutputKey"]: o
            for o in stack.get("Outputs", [])
        }
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        print(f"Unable to phase out exports for {stack_name} on {account}/{region}: {e}")
        return
 
    # load new template generated by CDK
    new_template = json.load(open(template_path))
    if "Outputs" not in new_template:
        new_template["Outputs"] = {}
 
    # get output names for both existing and new templates
    new_output_names = set(new_template["Outputs"].keys())
    old_output_names = set(old_outputs.keys())
 
    # phase out outputs that are in old template but not in new template
    for output_to_phase_out in old_output_names - new_output_names:
        # if we already marked it for removal last deploy, remove the output
        if old_outputs[output_to_phase_out].get("Description") == "REMOVE ON NEXT DEPLOY":
            print(f"Removing {output_to_phase_out}")
            continue
 
        if not old_outputs[output_to_phase_out].get("ExportName"):
            print(f"This is an export with no name, ignoring {old_outputs[output_to_phase_out]}")
            continue
 
        # add back removed outputs
        print(f"Re-adding {output_to_phase_out}, but removing on next deploy")
        new_template["Outputs"][output_to_phase_out] = {
            "Value": old_outputs[output_to_phase_out]["OutputValue"],
            "Export": {
                "Name": old_outputs[output_to_phase_out]["ExportName"]
            },
            # mark for removal on next deploy
            "Description": "REMOVE ON NEXT DEPLOY",
        }
 
    # replace template
    json.dump(new_template, open(template_path, "w"), indent=4)
 
 
def handle_assembly(assembly):
    for s in assembly.stacks:
        handle_template(s.stack_name, s.environment.account, s.environment.region, s.template_full_path)
 
    for a in assembly.nested_assemblies:
        handle_assembly(a.nested_assembly)
 
 
def main():
    assembly = cx_api.CloudAssembly("cdk.out")
    handle_assembly(assembly)
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Our deployment got a little more complicated and there were cases where the script phased-out an export but the next stack in the chain failed deployment. When the entire processed got retried, the script tried to remove the export but couldn't because the second stack didn't finish updating. I ended up using `cloudformation:ListImports` instead to figure out if an export is used or not. I will try to update the script here at some point but it may take a while.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [AWS CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) for infra-as-code development, this blog [CDK tips, part 3 – how to unblock cross-stack references](https://www.endoflineblog.com/cdk-tips-03-how-to-unblock-cross-stack-references) written by Adam Ruka, who worked on CDK for almost 7 years in Amazon, could be a very good guidance.

If you are on CDK version `1.90.1` or later, the key is to use the [exportValue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/%40aws-cdk/core/lib/stack.ts#L850-L896) function from the `stack` interface and do two consecutive deployments. The first one would ensure the parent stack preserves the exported values for the child stack to use.

See [Removing automatic cross-stack references - GitHub aws-cdk-lib](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/main/packages/aws-cdk-lib#removing-automatic-cross-stack-references) for more details.

That being said, I don't deny that this is a shortfall or design flaw that CDK and CloudFormation should have resolved more gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your issue like that: Create another cluster, migrate TaskDefinition with Service from old to the new cluster.

The thing is, that your old task is still is running as the error is telling you (SGs are still in use).
Additionally, could it be the case that you are trying to re-use the security groups from the old cluster?

If not so, then you need to instantiate a `new EcsServiceStack`, but with the new cluster argument.
Or if you don't care about a "manual blue/green deployment", then you can destroy the `old EcsServiceStack`.
Then rerun the CDK commands with the modification of the code should run.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-stack-export-name-error/) was usefull for me. In my case I was using CDK and wanted to remove one stack (lets say stackA) with outputs referenced as input in another stacks (lets say stackB and stackC). So I broke all cross stack references puting the value manually on the cloudFormation template and then I deployed the template to every stack (stackB and stackC). Then I removed the stackA on CDK and deployed and it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to manually create the outputs needed by setting the same `exportName` and value from the CloudFormation console in the cluster class:

```
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, `${this.id}clusterOutput`, { value: "sample-value", exportName: "ecs:ExportsOutputFnGetAttdefaultasgspotInstanceSecurityGroup2D2AFE98GroupId1084B7B2"});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `this.exportValue`, when you are removing dependency between two stacks to avoid this error:

```
this.exportValue(this.dynamodbTable.tableArn);
```

Take a look at [my blog](https://medium.com/@ranjithkumarsid/fix-aws-cdk-export-export-name-cannot-be-updated-as-it-is-in-use-by-stack-name-8a419b152b9d) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Second, given this seems to be your first offence: don't link-dump your own content. In addition to that: having a similar username on both sites is not sufficient attribution. Make it very *very* clear that you are linking to your own content. See [how not to be a spammer](/help/promotion). Repeated behaviour may lead to sanctions against your account.